# difference of two random distributions python

Tags: python, random, distribution, difference

Good day!
I have two gamma distributions, and want to find distribution of their difference.
Use `np.random.gamma` to generate distribution by parameters, but the resulting distribution is very different from time to time.
Code:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import gamma

for i in range(0, 10):
    s1 = np.random.gamma(1.242619972, 0.062172619, 2000) +  0.479719122 
    s2 = np.random.gamma(456.1387112, 0.002811328, 2000) - 0.586076723
    r_a, r_loc, r_scale = gamma.fit(s1 - s2)
    print(1 - gamma.cdf(0.0, r_a, r_loc, r_scale))
```

Result:

```
0.4795655021157602
0.07061938039031612
0.06960741675590854
0.4957568913729331
0.4889900326940878
0.07381963810128422
0.0690800784280835
0.07198551429809896
0.07659274505827551
0.06967441935502583
```

I receive two quite different cdf of 0.: 0.48 and 0.07. What can be the problem?

Comment: The difference between two Gamma distributions is not a Gamma it self - it is quite complicated. Please take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48378/difference-of-gamma-random-variables

Answer (score 1):

You're fitting a gamma distribution to the difference between two other gamma distributions. A gamma distribution can only be positive, so that makes no sense and you can't expect to get a consistent answer. If you print the mean difference you get consistent results.

Comment: you forget about `loc` parameter of fit function (when you say about distribution can only be positive).

Comment: It still makes no sense to model the difference with a gamma distribution. Gamma distributions have no upper bound, and if you subtract two from each other, you would imagine that the distribution should run on the interval [-inf, inf]. So a normal distribution would make more sense. I imagine that the highest value sampled will affect the results dramatically. If you add more samples it seem to converge towards 0.48.

Comment: how can i use scipy to get the generator of a probability distribution with min KL divergence?